# Tooltip missing for geom_line_interactive in ggiraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, survival-analysis, ggiraph

I wanted to add tooltip to `ggsurvplot`. I am using `ggiraph` to display the plot. Since `ggiraph` does not have `geom_step_interactive`, I am manipulating my the data output of `ggsurvplot` to get the step function values and using `geom_line_interactive` to overlay a line on my ggsurvplot and add a tooltip. Here is the code that is working correctly:

```
library(ggiraph)
library(survminer)
library(survival)

  #Function to get the step function points
  step_func <- function(data, direction="hv", x , y) {
    direction <- match.arg(direction, c("hv", "vh"))
    data <- as.data.frame(data)[order(data[, x]), ]
    n <- nrow(data)

    if (n <= 1) {
      # Need at least one observation
      return(data[0, , drop = FALSE])
    }

    if (direction == "vh") {
      xs <- rep(1:n, each = 2)[-2*n]
      ys <- c(1, rep(2:n, each = 2))
    } else {
      ys <- rep(1:n, each = 2)[-2*n]
      xs <- c(1, rep(2:n, each = 2))
    }

    return(data.frame(
      x = data[,x][xs],
      y = data[,y][ys],
      data[xs, setdiff(names(data), c(x, y))]
    ))
  }



  fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung )
  g <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung, risk.table = TRUE,
                  risk.table.pos= "out", risk.table.y.text = TRUE)

  dat1 <- plyr::ddply(g$plot$data, "strata", step_func, "hv", "time", "surv")
  dat1$tooltip <- paste0("Time:", dat1$x)
  gg<- g$plot+geom_line_interactive(data = dat1, aes(x= x, y=y, colour = strata, tooltip= tooltip ), size = .75)
  ggiraph(code = print(gg))
```

With the above code I get the following plot with tooltip as displayed in the image:[image]

I want the tooltip not only show the time but also the survival probability, for that I change the code slightly as follows:

`dat1$tooltip <- paste0("Time:", dat1$x, "Surv:", dat1$y )`

This causes the tooltip to disappear.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the `geom_line_interactive` tooltips vanish when they get too long. You can truncate the values result to keep them short. The following works:

```
dat1$tooltip <- paste0("Time:", dat1$x, " Surv:", round(dat1$y,2) )
```

but setting the value to 3 causes them to vanish. I am not completely sure of this because the tooltips are **extremely fiddly** and seemingly only appear when the the mouse is in exactly the right place. It could be that all of them over a certain length are suppressed.

I did notice however that the whole tooltip thing works much better if you use `geom_point_interactive` instead of `geom_line_interactve` and with larger `size` parameter values. That is probably what you want to do.

Could be that `geom_line_interactive` is ignoring the `size` parameter.

This figure is with `geom_point_interactive`, the `round` parameter above set to 3, and the `size` set to 1.75, and it works much better.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect! There seems to be some kind of a problem with the tooltip when you select `geom_line_interactive`. `geom_point_interactive` seems to be the perfect solution!

Comment: Thanks. Would appreciate an upvote by the way (working toward my badges and answer credits don't count to that)